# Facebook login API for javascript not working

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, facebook-javascript-sdk, app-id

Sorry for the bad indenting. This is the Facebook Login API. I am getting these errors in my javascript compiler...

Invalid App Id: Must be a number or numeric string representing the application id."         all.js:53

"FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init()." all.js:53

Content Security Policy: Couldn't parse invalid source chrome-extension://lifbcibllhkdhoafpjfnlhfpfgnpldfl

Content Security Policy: Failed to parse unrecognized source chrome-

extension://lifbcibllhkdhoafpjfnlhfpfgnpldfl

GET https://www.facebook.com/plugins/login_button.php [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 1072ms]
    "fb:login_button failed to resize in 45s"

I have definitely have the correct URL and app_id, my url is http://myimprint.herokuapp.com/

Please any help or direction...

```
 <html>

<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
   window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
   FB.init({
   appId      : '{283742071785556}',
   channelUrl : 'http://myimprint.herokuapp.com/',
   status     : true, // check login status
   cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
   xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
     });

  // Here we subscribe to the auth.authResponseChange JavaScript event. This event is         fired
 // for any authentication related change, such as login, logout or session refresh.   This means that
 // whenever someone who was previously logged out tries to log in again, the correct case below 
  // will be handled. 
      FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
   // Here we specify what we do with the response anytime this event occurs. 
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
     // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the app know the current
    // login status of the person. In this case, we're handling the situation where they 
    // have logged in to the app.
  testAPI();
} else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
  // In this case, the person is logged into Facebook, but not into the app, so we call
  // FB.login() to prompt them to do so. 
  // In real-life usage, you wouldn't want to immediately prompt someone to login 
  // like this, for two reasons:
  // (1) JavaScript created popup windows are blocked by most browsers unless they 
  // result from direct interaction from people using the app (such as a mouse click)
  // (2) it is a bad experience to be continually prompted to login upon page load.
  FB.login();
} else {
  // In this case, the person is not logged into Facebook, so we call the login() 
  // function to prompt them to do so. Note that at this stage there is no indication
  // of whether they are logged into the app. If they aren't then they'll see the Login
  // dialog right after they log in to Facebook. 
  // The same caveats as above apply to the FB.login() call here.
  FB.login();
          }
        });
      };

   // Load the SDK asynchronously
   (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document));

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is successful. 
  // This testAPI() function is only called in those cases. 
   function testAPI() {
   console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
   FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
   });
  }
  </script>
```

```
 <fb:login-button show-faces="true" width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
appId      : '283742071785556',
```

must solve the problem

Answer (score 5):

`Invalid App Id: Must be a number or numeric string representing the application id.`

Change this line:

```
appId      : '{283742071785556}',
```

to:

```
appId      : "283742071785556",   /* numeric string */
```

or

```
appId      : 283742071785556,  /* number */
```

Answer (score 2):

The App ID as string is definitely the main problem, but there is one other very important thing: You should always use FB.login in a mouse event listener. This is why:

- Users don´t want to be presented immediately with an authorization/login request when they open your Website/App. First, show them what your Website/App is about and present a "Login" button/link.
- Popup blockers may block the login window if you don´t open it in a mouse event listener. Login popups always appear as browser popup on an external Website.

Btw, you don´t really need the "fb:login-button" button if you use FB.login with the JavaScript SDK.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {  
    // for js api initialization
    FB.init({
    appId  : '{Your-16 digit App ID}',
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true, // parse XFBML
    oauth  : true // enable OAuth 2.0
    });
};
```

To fix this issue, just do a “Create New App” in the Apps section in Facebook. And then go back to the Facebook Social Plugins page, pick a plugin, and regenerate the code for it.

Your Facebook plugin code before having an App ID:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

After you have assigned an App to the plugin

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=<your-16-digit-app-id>";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Notice the difference in the highlighted code? Let me know if this solved your problem in the comment area.